# Lost syntax highlighting in Vim, but only for a certain file name

Tags: vim, server, syntax, highlight, vi

I work on a server and use vim, and occasionally the connection will break. When I regain connection, and try to reopen the files I was working on I choose to delete the old swap files (I frequently save). However, after I do this, all syntax highlighting will be gone from the file and it cannot even be returned by typing ":syntax on", but only so long as it has that file name.

For example, suppose I am working on a file called file.py. Then I lose connection, and reopen the file deleting the swp file. The syntax highlighting will be gone and ":syntax on" does nothing.

If I rename the file file2.py, then the highlighting returns. But, if I create a brand new file called file.py, then this new file will still not have syntax highlighting (note that this holds for all file extensions, not just .py).

Am I doing something wrong that initiates this? And, how do I fix it so I don't have do something ridiculous like rename all my files?

Comment: can you try deleting the swap file and then opening the file in vim

Comment: Might also need to mv the viminfo file away and see if that helps

Comment: Check filetype, try syntax enable, or running a colorscheme command as well

Comment: Have you tried `:set filetype=py` to manually update the file type detection?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem a few times now, and suspected that vim forgets the filetype for that file for some reason, perhaps when my ssh session dies due to a power outage.

`:filetype detect` fixed it for me.